# Stubbing a method which is called in class constructor in RhinoMocks

Tags: c#, mocking, rhino-mocks, rhino-mocks-3.5

My class has a method like this:

`internal virtual Something CreateSomething(){...}`

It was done this way so that in testing I can stub `CreateSomething()` to return a mock object:

```
var something = ...; //some mock object
var t = MockRepository.GenerateStub<MyObject>();
t.Stub(x => x.CreateSomething()).Return(something);
```

This worked fine but now `CreateSomething()` is called in the class constructor, before it was called later on, so by the time I stub the method my object is already created.

Is there a workaround that doesn't involve changing the design, to pass stub methods in at construction time? If not I can consider changing the design to use construction-injection (which I'm sure some of you are itching to suggest anyway!) but I'd rather see if Rhino supports this use-case first.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to stub the method before it is invoked from its class constructor. This is C# limitation. And this is reasonable.
In general it is a bad practice to call virtual method from the constructor, because likely the result will not be what is expected. See details here: [Virtual member call in a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119506/virtual-member-call-in-a-constructor).

So, I highly recommend to either make this method non-virtual, or avoid its invocation from the constructor.
Anyway in such situation it won't work as virtual.

Regarding you question about testing the method, which is called from constructor.
I presume, this is a private method. Otherwise it could be tested as a regular public method.
As it is private, then there is no need to test this particular method in isolation. I recommend to follow general approach in testing constructors and testing private methods:  Do not test private methods.
Test **the public visible effect** instead. That could be:

- Public property initialization
- Mocked dependencies invocation or properties access
- Exception thrown
- etc.

Please also find more details about this topic by the links below:
[Is it important to unit test a constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357929/is-it-important-to-unit-test-a-constructor)
[Unit testing private methods in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122708/unit-testing-private-methods-in-c-sharp)